# Google Universal Analytics: Send additional parameters in event tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I've set up an event tracker with UA, and I'm interested in passing extra key-value pairs with each event tracker call. [Google's documentation says](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced) an object can be passed as the last parameter of a call to `ga()`.

I've been able to successfully send calls this way:

```
var action = "Click edit button";
var category = "Button clicks";
var label = "Dashboard page";    
var attached_params = { 'username': 'bob', 'other_value': 'foobar' };
ga('send', 'event', action, category, label, attached_params);
```

It's reporting correctly, but the contents of attached_params are not visible in the Analytics Dashboard. Am I doing this correctly? What's the right way to pass in these additional parameters and have access to their values in the Analytics Dashboard?

Comment: GA does not have dimensions that are names "username" etc. You have to create custom dimensions in the backend and send them in the code as dimension1, dimension2 .... up to dimension 20. However you can name them when you create them so that in the reports they will appear under your chosen names.

Comment: I've seen "Dimensions and Metrics" in the documentation– Can metrics take string values?

Comment: No. Metrics are always numbers.

Comment: Is passing string values through Universal Analytics this way impossible then?

Comment: No. Dimensions are strings, metrics are numbers. If you want to send a string you'd have to use a custom dimension. If you want to set up a counter you'd have to use a metric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing values to Universal Analytics in this way is not currently possible.  This is however a perfect use case for custom dimensions

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets

```
ga('send', 'event', category, action, label, {
  'dimension1': 'bob', // username
  'dimension1': 'foobar' // other_value
});
```